# How to bind custom error to a Template Driven form input field in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

In case of Model Driven form or Reactive form we can bind the custom error to an input field as follows:

**In Component:**

`sampleForm.controls["formControlName"].setErrors({ 'incorrect': true })`;

**My question is how can we do the same thing in case of Template Driven form?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of `View Child` in this scenario get an instance of the `ngForm` in the component backend model and then add all the validations and errors to it

Something like this

```
f: NgForm; // f is nothing but the template reference of the Template Driven Form
@ViewChild('f') currentForm: NgForm;
currentForm.form.controls["formControlName"].setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
```

For More detailed info check my ts file which i created for such a scenario [`link`](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/template-driven/template-driven.component.ts)